# Contextless navigation error in flutter when coming back from backfround using callkeep

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-getx, callkit

Okay, I'm stuck in this for about 3 months.
I need to get a way to open my app in a specific page when coming from background.
I'm using a callkeep package([flutter_callkit_incoming](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming): ^1.0.3+3) to open my app whenever i receive a notification through my firebase. Everything works fine when I'm on foreground, the callkeep is activated, the page transition works and etc. The problem starts when I'm trying to get the app back from the background.

```
Future<void> _fcmBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  print('Acho q isso chegou por aqui: ${message.data}');
  //Random random = new Random();
  PushNotificationData pushData = PushNotificationData.fromJson(message.data);
  if (message.data['action'] == "Incoming call") {
    final callUUID = Uuid().v4();
    final params = callKeepParams(pushData);
    await FlutterCallkitIncoming.showCallkitIncoming(params);
    var calls = await FlutterCallkitIncoming.activeCalls();
    FlutterCallkitIncoming.onEvent.listen((event) {
      print(event);
      onCallKeepEventReceived(event, pushData);
    });
    return null;
  }
```

my fcmBackgroundHandler. The error lies on the "onCallKeepEventReceived" method.

```
onCallKeepEventReceived(CallEvent? event, PushNotificationData pushData) {
  switch (event!.event) {
    case Event.ACTION_CALL_START:
      break;
    case Event.ACTION_CALL_ACCEPT:
      backgroundFunctionOnAccept(pushData);
      break;
    case Event.ACTION_CALL_DECLINE:
      backgroundFunctionOnDecline(pushData);
      break;
    case Event.ACTION_CALL_ENDED:
      backgroundFunctionOnHangUp(pushData);
      break;
    case Event.ACTION_CALL_TIMEOUT:
      backgroundFunctionOnTimeOut(pushData);
      break;
}
}
```

And whenever I accept the call with the callKepp, It gets to the "Event.ACTION_CALL_ACCEPT" case

```
Future<void> backgroundFunctionOnAccept(PushNotificationData pushData) async {
  print(pushData);
  Get.to(() => ChamadaView(),
      transition: Transition.upToDown,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.easeIn);      
  return null;
}
```

This is where I get stuck. Everytime this function get's called when coming from the background, I ended up with the error: Unhandled Exception: You are trying to use contextless navigation without a GetMaterialApp or Get.key.

How can I solve this issue?